# Django asymmetric relationship: return intersect

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm using Django 2.1.3 with Python 3.6.6. 
I have two models, a custom User model and a Connection model to track relationships between users, defined as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import 

class User(AbstractUser):
    # (additional fields)
    connections_sent = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        through='Connection',
        # through_fields=('from_user', 'to_user'),
        related_name='connections_received',
        symmetrical=False,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def add_connection(self, user):
        connection, created = Connection.objects.get_or_create(
            from_user=self,
            to_user=user,
        )
        return connection

    def remove_connection(self, user):
        Connection.objects.filter(
            from_user=self,
            to_user=user,
        ).delete()
        return


class Connection(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='from_users', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='to_users', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('from_user', 'to_user')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Connection from {} to {}".format(self.from_user, self.to_user)
```

The idea is that (similar to LinkedIn), Users can send connection requests to other users (connections_sent), which the receiving user must confirm before further interaction can occur.

I would like to define a function `User.get_confirmed_connections(self)` which filters `connections_sent` so that only confirmed connections are returned. I.e. it should return the intersect between `connections_sent` and `connections_received`. Can this be done with filters?

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need to put some kind of flag which identifies if the relation is verified or not. You can add that in `Connection` model. Try like this:

```
class Connection(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='from_users', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='to_users', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and add the following method in the CustomUser:

```
def get_confirmed_connection(self):
    return self.from_users.filter(from_users__is_verified=True)
```